# What are the options for repairing a rare integrated circuit?

Tags: integrated-circuit, repair

Imagine: you have a relatively old, rare electronic device (like an arcade machine prototype) that you love, and it's broken. After some research, you find out that one of the main integrated circuits is faulty, but you can't get a replacement. So what do you do next? How do you repair your favorite device?

You can probably order reverse engineering of the chip with its subsequent cloning. That would cost a lot of money, wouldn't it? So it's not an option for the average person. Perhaps you can save money if you order only the chip research, and create it already in a conventional, non-integrated format. But it would still cost at least $1000, and probably much more, right? Considering that if this chip were on the market now, it would cost like $15.

Aren't there any other options? If you imagine that there are no other such chips anywhere, and the developers no longer exist. Is it possible to do repair inside the chip? As another option, perhaps you could get a similar chip and modify it somehow?

[image: Integrated circuit, just for reference]

Comment: What IC is this specifically about? There could be many options, just look at how the retrocomputing community managed to reverse- and re-engineer many of the old, specialized, IC's found in their favorite 8-bit home computers or game consoles. Some ICs are still being made (or something close) and can be adapted, some can be replaced by relatively simple logic, or more advanced programmable logic. There have been [Raspberry Pi's turned into sound chips for 8-bit home computers](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=75539) and so on. It all depends on if it can be reverse engineered.

Comment: You ripped that photo. It is a photo of reverse engineering Yamaha YM3812 OPL2 sound chip; taken by Olli Niemitalo and Matthew Gambrell. One of them a member of EE.SE. If you are talking about OPL2 chips, they are reverse engineered almost bit-accurately by now, and chips are still available so repair is easy.

Comment: The photo is just for reference, as well as arcade machine example; the question is completely theoretical - I hope I never face such a situation, but it would be interesting what to do if.

Answer (score 2):

Some "gaming" ICs actually have been reverse-engineered and produced by the retro games enthousiasts community; you could inquire there. Also, many things are possible with unlimited money, but without a larger community to do the work, or crowd source it, this will be *very* expensive. Repairing structures inside the silicon I don't see happening, but somebody may correct me.

You could look on Ebay and the likes (there is an active market in old and obsolete ICs).

These first two options require a type number or a very precise description. (Do you have a part number? What does it do?)

If all else fails, finding out the functionality of the IC and recreating that functionality with modern components, a microcontroller, or an FPGA, is your best bet. This solution will have a different form factor and not look "original", but it will at least work.

Before throwing money at this, make absolutely sure the IC is the cause of the problem.

Comment: Or an FPGA. If it's an analog IC, you're SOL.

Comment: @DKNguyen FPAAs do exist, though they're *extremely* specialist parts.

Comment: Repairing structures inside the die is possible, though usually done as a method of debugging during development of ICs. It's only routine to modify metal layers; modifying the silicon is extremely impractical. A focused ion beam (or FIB, an acronym also used sometimes to refer to the whole process) is used to make sub-micron-scale incisions into the die and expose or cut any metal that needs to be exposed or cut, then new metal is deposited on top to form new wires, connecting things that need to be connected. The process requires knowledge of the die's layout, and is very expensive.

Comment: @Hearth: Never knew that could be done. For debugging, you say; is it cheaper than baking a new one with the changes?

Comment: @ocrdu Yes, it costs several hundred dollars per die, but a new run costs minimum $10k. Of course, the new run would give you more reliable parts (the deposited metal can fail to attach well and lose connection) and a lot more of them, but for debugging, I'd much prefer to pay $500 to make sure the proposed fix will fix it than $10,000 only to find out that it didn't.

Comment: The repair process is also much quicker. At my workplace, we've shipped out bad dice to a company in Taiwan, paid them a few thousand dollars, and had the repaired ones back in about a week, and we were able to confirm that the proposed repair worked shortly thereafter. Rolling a new wafer takes months or as much as a year, unless you have an in-house wafer fab (or you have Connections at TSMC or XFab or someone, presumably).